# I need to export data from the Grid-view image attached to XML

Tags: c#, xml

Can anybody tell me why the code above is not producing the xml elements below

```
    <EmployeeHours>
<employeeId>101631</employeeId>
<workDays>
<workDay>
<date>2017-06-12</date>
<hourEntries>
<hourEntry>
<hours>7.5</hours>
<jobTitleCode>10</jobTitleCode>
<payTypeCode>3</payTypeCode>
</hourEntry>
</hourEntries>
</workDay>
<workDay>
<date>2017-06-13</date>
<hourEntries>
<hourEntry>
<hours>7.5</hours>
<jobTitleCode>10</jobTitleCode>
<payTypeCode>3</payTypeCode>
</hourEntry>
</hourEntries>
</workDay>
</workDays>
</EmployeeHours>
<EmployeeHours>
<employeeId>103673</employeeId>
<workDays>
<workDay>
<date>2017-06-18</date>
<hourEntries>
<hourEntry>
<hours>12.75</hours>
<jobTitleCode>9</jobTitleCode>
<payTypeCode>3</payTypeCode>
</hourEntry>
</hourEntries>
</workDay>
</workDays>
</EmployeeHours>
```

Instead of the following code

```
<EmployeeHours>
<employeeId>101631</employeeId>
<workDays>
<workDay>
<date>2017-06-12</date>
<hourEntries>
<hourEntry>
<hours>7.5</hours>
<jobTitleCode>10</jobTitleCode>
<payTypeCode>3</payTypeCode>
</hourEntry>
</hourEntries>
</workDay>
</workDays>
<workDays>
<workDay>
<date>2017-06-13</date>
<hourEntries>
<hourEntry>
<hours>7.5</hours>
<jobTitleCode>10</jobTitleCode>
<payTypeCode>3</payTypeCode>
</hourEntry>
</hourEntries>
</workDay>
</workDays>
<employeeId>103673</employeeId>
<workDays>
<workDay>
<date>2017-06-18</date>
<hourEntries>
<hourEntry>
<hours>12.75</hours>
<jobTitleCode>9</jobTitleCode>
<payTypeCode>3</payTypeCode>
</hourEntry>
</hourEntries>
</workDay>
</workDays>
</EmployeeHours>
```

I have attached an image of the gridview data for clarity 
[image]

and below is the complete code i use to generate the xml.

```
 XmlElement EmployeeHours = xmlDoc.CreateElement("EmployeeHours");
                foreach (GridViewRow row2 in GridView1.Rows)

                {
                    XmlElement EmployeeCode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("employeeId");
                XmlElement WorkDays = xmlDoc.CreateElement("workDays");

                  if (EmployeeID != row2.Cells[0].Text)
                    {

                        EmployeeHours.AppendChild(EmployeeCode);
                        EmployeeCode.InnerText = row2.Cells[0].Text;
                        EmployeeID = row2.Cells[0].Text;

                    }

                    XmlElement WorkDay = xmlDoc.CreateElement("workDay");
                    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.PrependChild(WorkDay);
                    WorkDays.AppendChild(WorkDay);
                    EmployeeHours.AppendChild(WorkDays);
                    parentNode.AppendChild(EmployeeHours);
                    //Third node and data source
                    XmlElement Date = xmlDoc.CreateElement("date");
                    WorkDay.AppendChild(Date);
                    DateTime converteddate = DateTime.ParseExact(row2.Cells[1].Text, fromFormat, null);
                    Date.InnerText = converteddate.ToString(toFormat);


                    XmlElement hourEntries = xmlDoc.CreateElement("hourEntries");
                    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.PrependChild(hourEntries);
                    WorkDay.AppendChild(hourEntries);

                    XmlElement HourEntry = xmlDoc.CreateElement("hourEntry");
                    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.PrependChild(HourEntry);
                    hourEntries.AppendChild(HourEntry);

                    //Fourth node and data source
                    XmlElement Hours = xmlDoc.CreateElement("hours");
                    HourEntry.AppendChild(Hours);
                    Hours.InnerText = row2.Cells[2].Text;

                    XmlElement JobTitleCode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("jobTitleCode");
                    HourEntry.AppendChild(JobTitleCode);
                    JobTitleCode.InnerText = row2.Cells[3].Text;

                    XmlElement payTypeCode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("payTypeCode");
                    HourEntry.AppendChild(payTypeCode);
                    payTypeCode.InnerText = row2.Cells[4].Text;

                    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.InsertAfter(parentNode, xmlDoc.DocumentElement.LastChild);
                    EmployeeID = row2.Cells[0].Text;

                }
```

I really appreciate your direction on what is missing from my code, it has to be something stupidly simple that i am overlooking.
Thank you

For those who asked for my complete code see below and this works just fine but he output is not what is expected the output ( the second part of the code is where the problem is..)
 try
            {

```
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dtxml = (DataTable)ViewState["Data"];
            ds.Tables.Add(dtxml);

            //Create a new XML doc
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            string dt = Txtendhour.Text.Replace("/", "");


            // Write down the XML declaration
            //Server.MapPath("directory.xml")
            if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("PPE" + dt + ".xml")))
            {
                File.Delete(Server.MapPath("PPE" + dt + ".xml"));
            }

            XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "ASCII", null);
            // Create the root element
            XmlElement rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("companyData");
            rootNode.SetAttribute("xmlns", "");
            xmlDoc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, xmlDoc.DocumentElement);
            xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);

            XmlElement headernode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("header");
            headernode.SetAttribute("fileSpecVersion", "2.00.0");
            xmlDoc.DocumentElement.PrependChild(headernode);
            // Create the required nodes
            XmlElement mainNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("companyId");
            XmlElement descNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("stateCode");
            XmlElement activeNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("reportQuarter");
            XmlElement fiscalYear = xmlDoc.CreateElement("federalFiscalYear");
            XmlElement Vendor = xmlDoc.CreateElement("softwareVendorName");
            XmlElement version = xmlDoc.CreateElement("softwareProductName");
            XmlElement vendorversion = xmlDoc.CreateElement("softwareProductVersion");

            // retrieve the text
            string faccode = txtcode.Text;
            string quarter = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[7].Text;
            XmlText categoryText = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(faccode);
            XmlText descText = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode("State");
            XmlText activeText = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(quarter);
            XmlText fiscalYearactiveText = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode("2017");
            XmlText activetext2 = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode("softwarename");
            XmlText activetext3 = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode("Softwaretype");
            XmlText activetext4 = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode("VersionNumber");

            // append the nodes to the parentNode without the value
            headernode.AppendChild(mainNode);
            headernode.AppendChild(descNode);
            headernode.AppendChild(activeNode);
            headernode.AppendChild(fiscalYear);
            headernode.AppendChild(Vendor);
            headernode.AppendChild(version);
            headernode.AppendChild(vendorversion);
            // save the value of the fields into the nodes
            mainNode.AppendChild(categoryText);
            descNode.AppendChild(descText);
            activeNode.AppendChild(activeText);
            fiscalYear.AppendChild(fiscalYearactiveText);
            Vendor.AppendChild(activetext2);
            version.AppendChild(activetext3);
            vendorversion.AppendChild(activetext4);

            // Create a new <Employees> element and add it to the root node
            XmlElement Employees = xmlDoc.CreateElement("employees");
            xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(Employees);

            XmlElement parentNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("EmployeeHours");

            // Set attribute name and value!
            parentNode.SetAttribute("processType", "merge");
            // xmlDoc.DocumentElement.PrependChild(parentNode);

            string id = "";
            string employeeCode = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text;



            string fromFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
            string toFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                //first part of EMPLOYEES ELEMENTS AND CHILD ELEMENTS

                if (id != row.Cells[0].Text)
                {
                    XmlElement employee = xmlDoc.CreateElement("employee");
                    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(employee);
                    Employees.AppendChild(employee);
                    //create the element
                    XmlElement EmployeeID1= xmlDoc.CreateElement("employeeId");
                    employee.AppendChild(EmployeeID1);
                    EmployeeID1.InnerText = row.Cells[0].Text;

                    XmlElement HireDate1 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("hireDate");
                    employee.AppendChild(HireDate1);
                    DateTime newdate = DateTime.ParseExact(row.Cells[6].Text, fromFormat, null);

                    HireDate1.InnerText = newdate.ToString(toFormat);//row.Cells[6].Text;
                    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.InsertAfter(Employees, xmlDoc.DocumentElement.LastChild);
                    id = row.Cells[0].Text;
                }
            }


            string employeenumber = "";

          XmlElement staffHours = xmlDoc.CreateElement("empoyeeHours");
            foreach (GridViewRow row2 in GridView1.Rows)

            {
                XmlElement EmployeeCode= xmlDoc.CreateElement("employeeId");
            XmlElement WorkDays = xmlDoc.CreateElement("workDays");

              if (nursenumber != row2.Cells[0].Text)
                {

                    staffHours.AppendChild(NurseIdCode);
                    employeeCode.InnerText = row2.Cells[0].Text;
                    employeenumber = row2.Cells[0].Text;

                }

                XmlElement WorkDay = xmlDoc.CreateElement("workDay");
                xmlDoc.DocumentElement.PrependChild(WorkDay);
                WorkDays.AppendChild(WorkDay);
                staffHours.AppendChild(WorkDays);
                parentNode.AppendChild(staffHours);
                //Third node and data source
                XmlElement Date = xmlDoc.CreateElement("date");
                WorkDay.AppendChild(Date);
                DateTime converteddate = DateTime.ParseExact(row2.Cells[1].Text, fromFormat, null);
                Date.InnerText = converteddate.ToString(toFormat);


                XmlElement hourEntries = xmlDoc.CreateElement("hourEntries");
                xmlDoc.DocumentElement.PrependChild(hourEntries);
                WorkDay.AppendChild(hourEntries);

                XmlElement HourEntry = xmlDoc.CreateElement("hourEntry");
                xmlDoc.DocumentElement.PrependChild(HourEntry);
                hourEntries.AppendChild(HourEntry);

                //Fourth node and data source
                XmlElement Hours = xmlDoc.CreateElement("hours");
                HourEntry.AppendChild(Hours);
                Hours.InnerText = row2.Cells[2].Text;

                XmlElement JobTitleCode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("jobTitleCode");
                HourEntry.AppendChild(JobTitleCode);
                JobTitleCode.InnerText = row2.Cells[3].Text;

                XmlElement payTypeCode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("payTypeCode");
                HourEntry.AppendChild(payTypeCode);
                payTypeCode.InnerText = row2.Cells[4].Text;

                xmlDoc.DocumentElement.InsertAfter(parentNode, xmlDoc.DocumentElement.LastChild);
                employeenumber = row2.Cells[0].Text;

            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblMessage.Visible = true;
            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

Comment: Can you tell me where the problem is? Which line in the XML is not as you like?

Comment: The first XML is invalid. It has 2 root nodes.

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Make sure the code is compiling.  Check the bin folder in the project and verify the exe matches the data time when you last compiled.  The xml is not matching the code posted so I assume the code wasn't compiled properly.

Comment: The code compiles just fine i think the problem is when the file is generated it either does not close the employeehours element after it changes ID it only closes it once at the end by adding all employees under one elements where each employee may work more than one day and therefore close the employee hours after the last day worked. i can share some more code which is the complete code but the first part of the file works just fine i'ts the second part where i am getting the data from the grid view to display it the way i described above.

Answer (score 0):

The first XML example is invalid, and you can check it by loading it in Visual Studio. It will show you multiple root elements. In order to avoid such kind of issues in the first place, the best way to create XML is with the use of [DataTable.WriteXML() Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3zy2whb(v=vs.110).aspx).

But since you have a specific format in which the XML output is needed, the correct way to achieve this, is by applying an XSLT Transform to a DataSet.

See this code sample -

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
StringBuilder sbXslOutput = new StringBuilder();

using (XmlWriter xslWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sbXslOutput))
{
    XslCompiledTransform transformer = new XslCompiledTransform();
    transformer.Load("transformer.xsl");
    XsltArgumentList args = new XsltArgumentList();

    transformer.Transform(new XmlDataDocument(ds), args, xslWriter);
}

string dataSetHtml = sbXslOutput.ToString();
```

Here's is the example which explains in details what you need to do-

[Applying an XSLT Transform to a DataSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/applying-an-xslt-transform-to-a-dataset)

Comment: Please see the complete code above i just updated yesterday to have an idea. it works but just does not do the nodes right.